# Opening URL in WebView from Apple Push Notification ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiwebview, apple-push-notifications

Here is a problem:

1. Trying to send push notification with URL
2. Openinig only on last url, not that it Push

can I open WebView controller in didReceiveRemoteNotification?

**EDIT**: is there any posibility to open webview with another url (not the initial one)?

Comment: how about just opening the URL in safari? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416469/how-to-launch-safari-and-open-url-from-ios-app

Comment: no, sorry, but, safari not an option.

On different push notification - there are different url in personal profile open

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification is only called (I believe) if your app is currently open. Otherwise, if the user actions the notification, you can check your options in `didFinishLanuchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: Tried - with not luck.

Also tried in didReceiveRemoteNotification the following code, but it didn't open WebView at all: 

` UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"main" bundle:nil];
 WebViewController* pvc = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebView"];
 [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:NULL];
`

Comment: *where* are you trying this?

Comment: just found the solution: my mistake was putting [WebView reload] in WillAppear.
After removing it - everything working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found the solution: my mistake was putting `[WebView reload]` in `WillAppear`. After removing it - everything working