# Performing a task through a website and going back to an iOS app

Tags: ios, url, redirect, uiwebview, safari

I'm developing an iOS 7+ app that I need to offer the option of navigating to a certain web page to let the users to fill in a form there, and after that to come back to the app's view where the user was.

Is it possible to programmatically open `Safari` with a given url? If it is, I suppose that then there is no way to automatically redirect the user to your app from there... right? Is then a `UIWebView` the only option? Is it possible to navigate back or dismiss the view with the `UIWebView` without the need of user interaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can open links in Safari as detailed in this post [How to launch safari and open URL from iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416469/how-to-launch-safari-and-open-url-from-ios-app)

I don't believe you can set a 'callback' and have it return to your app on completion, as you have no control over the user once they have exited your app's sandbox.

Opening the link in UIWebView would provide control, as you can utilize the UIWebView callbacks.