# Switch to home screen from Safari on iOS

Tags: ios, web, hyperlink, safari, homescreen

Actually, I have a website with a single link that install a .ipa.
The installation starts in background do my question is:

-Is there a way to switch from Safari (or whatever browser) to the home screen when de link is pressed?

I've experienced that behavior when adding a web to the home screen, but I'm not able to find any info about that.

Comment: No. (at least i hope so) Once again for the simple reason that it would feel wrong, you cannot just switch between apps and the home screen programmatically - it conflicts with the UX.

Comment: perhaps see this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416469/how-to-launch-safari-and-open-url-from-ios-app