# How can I can make a link open in safari from my mobile app?

Tags: ios, paypal, safari

In this app I have it so you can donate using paypal but donating directly from the app is against the App Store Review Guidelines. I'm using an app builder because to make this app so I can't directly edit the source code.

> While donations may not be taken within an application, you may provide a link to your website that launches Safari for users to make a donation.

What would I need to add on my website that would launch a link in safari on mobile?

Comment: You need to add something in your **app**, right? Why would you want to add something on a website that launches **another browser instance**? That would just be a simple link... You are already in the browser, then it is not an app... This is confusing, please clarify.

Comment: So in the app you click a donate button that opens a link to paypal in app. The problem is that it's against the review guidelines to have donations like that in app so I want to have it where you click the button and opens the link in safari. I'm creating the app with an app builder called zapable and all I can do for this is add buttons that open web pages in app. So by clicking the button it will open the webpage in app that will open paypal in safari. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: i am not a ios developer but i think this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416469/how-to-launch-safari-and-open-url-from-ios-app

Comment: i think this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416469/how-to-launch-safari-and-open-url-from-ios-app

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with this code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.paypal.com"]];
```