# How to add a hyperlink button on iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a clickable link over a button.
I made this using some Internet help but it didn't work :

```
    @IBAction func linkClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    openUrl("http://fr.envisite.net/t5exce")
}
func openUrl(url:String!) {

    let targetURL=NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)

    let application=UIApplication.sharedApplication()

    application.openURL(targetURL);

}
```

It doesn't do anything, no error, just the button doesn't get me on Safari (I use the iOS simulator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch safari and open URL from iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416469/how-to-launch-safari-and-open-url-from-ios-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating a file URL with a web url string. Use the NSURL String constructor instead.

```
@IBAction func linkClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    openUrl("http://fr.envisite.net/t5exce")
}

func openUrl(urlStr:String!) {

     if let url = NSURL(string:urlStr) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}

   }
```

**Swift3**

```
@IBAction func linkClicked(sender: Any) {
    openUrl(urlStr: "http://fr.envisite.net/t5exce")
}

func openUrl(urlStr: String!) {
    if let url = URL(string:urlStr), !url.absoluteString.isEmpty {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't see what's different but it works ^^

Comment: @Orionss -  fileURLWithPath - we are using for local path , NSURL(string: - we are using server path or web url Path,

Comment: @Orionss - happy to hear,

Comment: In Swift 3 you should use `URL` instead of `NSURL` - that way, no need for `url as URL`.

Comment: I am using a textview for my link, but unable to connect to this function: func linkClicked or make an action.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @LizG -   are you created the function in your current class

Comment: Yes. After viewDidLoad

Comment: @LizG - can you attach the project I will check

Comment: I am not near my mac atm but will as soon as i am. Thank you