# Swift UIAlertController with url in text

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have this code:

```
func alertBox(txt: String){
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "MyTtle" , message: "More information in my website: ", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let ramkaNaObrazek = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        let ikonaAlertu = UIImageView(frame: ramkaNaObrazek)
        ikonaAlertu.image = UIImage(named: "modal_podpowiedz")
        ac.view.addSubview(ikonaAlertu)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok" , style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        }))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
```

I would like to add after this text: "More information in my website:" + www - a link to my website (http://www.myname.pl).

How can I do this?

Comment: try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392939/how-to-add-a-hyperlink-button-on-ios-swift)

Comment: you want this link tappable? in that case you should add an action button that will load your website

Comment: you want to open the link on Ok buttons click.?

Comment: No, I would like to open the browser after clicking on the label/text: "http://www.myname.pl"

Comment: I wonder you need to use custom alert box for this. If you want i can give you the code to open URL using the OK button

Comment: Yes, please show me yours code :)

Comment: Don't use _polski_ in your code! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add custom fields like text views with clickable links to a `UIAlertController`. You will need to either create your own modal view controller that acts like a `UIAlertController` or use a third party framework that does it for you.