# ios - website links within webview app not opening in safari

Tags: ios, webview

Background: Using Xcode 8.3, swift 3, compiling for ios version 8

I have a very simple app that's just using webview to display my website.  My website has external links(using hrefs) which I want to open in Safari when user clicks, not in my app's webview.

I found many similar questions with very similar answers.  I tried to incorporate the answers I found, however, I cannot get mine to work.

Hoping to get some clarity.

Here is my code:

**ViewController code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var siteView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    siteView.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let url = URL(string: "myurlgoeshere")

    siteView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
}
```

**AppDelegate code**

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, 
    navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked {

        guard let url = request.url else { return true }

        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url) //ios 8 version of open

        return false
    }
    return true

}
```

When I run the above code and click on link, they keep opening in my app.

I am running my code in the ios simulator, so not sure if that is keeping the links from opening in Safari.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Plz check Transport security policy if it has not secure website.

Comment: I think I had to set this previously because my url is not https, however, the external links are.  I wonder if there is a conflict now.

Comment: no worries Transport security only for our app not for safari.

Comment: May be it will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416469/how-to-launch-safari-and-open-url-from-ios-app