# Making a weblink in c++

Tags: c++

I wanted to know if it is possible to write  code in ANSI C/C++ so that from an executable i should be redirected to the original link.

I have a dialog box on this dialog box i have a about me menu option in this " about me "
menu option i want to have a link to an external website say www.google.com.The dialog box is created in c++.
For example,

```
On click of Google->www.google.co.in
```

Can this be possible using acrobat sdk?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please extend your question? To me, at least, it is not clear what you try to achieve.

Comment: The acrobat SDK is not going to be of any help here. Why do you bring it up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [making a weblink work from a dialog box in adobe reader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705266/making-a-weblink-work-from-a-dialog-box-in-adobe-reader)

Answer (score 2):

This is not actually possible in ANSI C/C++ without operating-system specific extensions. So the answer to this question will depend on what operating system you're targetting.

On Linux, recently distributions have been including an [xdg-open wrapper script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5116553/36723) to invoke the default browser. You can use `system()` or `fork()` and [one of the `exec*()` family of functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) to invoke it.

On Windows, [use `ShellExecute` to open the default browser.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816)

On Mac OS X, use the `open` CLI call via `system` or `fork()` and `exec` (as in Linux), [or you can use the Core Foundation native calls.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4177902/36723)

On Android, [send a browser intent.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2201999/36723) And on iPhone, [there are some calls to open the browser as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3989642/36723)

All of this I got by googling for things like "windows open browser url". I encourage you to try using search engines to find API references in the future; for finding the right API call, this is often a lot faster than asking on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open it in the default browser, you should execute an appropriate command for your OS. For example, to open Google in Firefox under Linux in a new tab, you will have to execute

`firefox -new-tab "http://www.google.com"`

This can be done via a call to the `system()` function, e.g.:

`system( "firefox -new-tab \"http://www.google.com\"" );`

If you want the site to appear inside of your application, you will have to integrate the browser into it. Many modern IDEs have built-in browser widgets that can handle basic operations, and can be easily integrated into your app.

Comment: is tthis the code that i need to write